# how to encrypt the password in django model?

Tags: python, django

[model class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwa69.png)

```
 class user(models.Model):
     password = CharField(max_length=50)
```

So, the password field should not be visible instead it should be displayed as *

Answer (score 0):

You can use make_password function. Please check bellow link for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password

Comment: now  i have a question how to convert encrpyt data into decrypt data